# Parse error with ImportJSON in google sheets, too many arguments

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

While trying to build a price tracking app in google sheets I'm running into an issue.  I have added the following function to google sheets App Scripts:
https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

Now when I try to call this function from any cell I'm getting a parse error.

I am a total novice at this, but I believe I am following the proper syntax mentioned in ImportJSON github page liked above, and in this article issued by to the site I am trying to call data from:
https://www.coingecko.com/learn/crypto-portfolio-tracker-google-sheets

I can access the API url without issue.
[API request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hAc1.png)

For example when I try this:
`=IMPORTJSON(“https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C30d&locale=en&precision=3?&x_cg_demo_api_key=MY_KEY”,“/name,/current_price,/market_cap,/price_change,/total_volume,/high_24h,/low_24h”,“noTruncate”,doNotDelete!$A$1)`

(note I omitted my private API key above)

[error says ImportJSON only takes 3 arguments, hinting at the underlined red section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjKos.png)

As suggested below I should try and remove either “noTruncate” or doNotDelete!$A$1 however this still returns the same error.  Google sheets is telling me I have 9 arguments somehow.[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpEXj.jpg)

Appears the current formula is seeing each of these as an argument:

1. “https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C30d&locale=en&precision=3?&x_cg_demo_api_key=MY_KEY”
2. /name
3. /current_price
4. /market_cap
5. /price_change
6. /total_volume
7. /high_24h
8. /low_24h
9. “noTruncate”
10. doNotDelete!$A$1

#2-8 should be grouped together somehow as should #9-10

Are there some special brackets I should be using around each argument?

Answer (score 0):

The coingecko site provides an example formula (including url) which you have used in your question. However there are two slight differences between the urls.

**DIFF#1**
Coingecko:

- `https://pro-api.coingecko.com`

Formula:

- `https://api.coingecko.com`

**DIFF#2**
Coingecko:

- `x_cg_pro_api_key`

Formula:

- `x_cg_demo_api`